# NODE JS - Delete all files execept content list

Tags: node.js

My function is:

```
function Delete(dir){
    log(`[DELETE] ${dir}.`)
    fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    files.forEach(file => {
        const fileDir = path.join(dir, file);

        if (file !== 'specialfile.txt') {
           fs.rm(fileDir, { recursive:true }, (err) => {
        if(err){
        // File deletion failed
        console.error(err.message);
        return;
        }
        })
        }
    });
});
```

But he only preserves the "specialfile.txt" not the content file in case i like preserver a list of files inside in "specialfile.txt".

specialfile.txt:

```
error.dll
Windows.txt
jose.cfg
```

Comment: So am I understanding that `specialfile.txt` contains a list of filenames, and those filenames should be _excluded_ from being deleted?

Comment: @Evert tnx for response, it contains the list of files that will not be deleted.

Comment: Ok, so what's missing at the very least is that you're never reading that file. You want to read the file first, and make an array with those files so you can loop through the files and compare it to the list.

Comment: @Evert how can make it?